# Как вывести фото по тегу из instagram без лишних авторизаций?

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

Пытаюсь вывести фото из инстраграма по некому хештегу. Есть страница, где нужно пользователям показывать фид последних фоток по этому тегу.

При этом нужно, чтобы пользователь просто зашел и увидел фото, а не авторизовался в приложении, чтобы увидеть контент...

Я так понимаю у инстаграма поменялся API и условия работы, поэтому примеры из интернета не работают... Помогите понять логику и алгоритм работы в данном случае.

---

Идеально тыкнуть РАБОЧИМ примером. Я пробовал такое, но не работает.

```
function callInstagram($url)
{
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
CURLOPT_URL => $url,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2
));

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $result;
}

$tag = 'YOUR_TAG_HERE';
$client_id = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID";
$url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/'.$tag.'/media/recent?client_id='.$client_id;

$inst_stream = callInstagram($url);
$results = json_decode($inst_stream, true);

//Now parse through the $results array to display your results... 
foreach($results['data'] as $item){
    $image_link = $item['images']['low_resolution']['url'];
    echo '<img src="'.$image_link.'" />';
}
```

Как же все-таки поступить правильно?

Comment: Я понял, что нужно еще использовать и токен теперь. Но когда даже его использую приходит пустой ответ... Вот ответ:

    {"pagination":{"deprecation_warning":"next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead"},"meta":{"code":200},"data":[]}

Comment: @Seredniy, у вас прямым текстом написано "next_max_id и min_id устарели; используйте вместо них min_tag_id и max_tag_id" - что из этого именно вам не понятно?

Comment: Я вообще не использую эти параметры, а даже если и меняю их на новые - все ровно такое сообщение. Массив с изображениями пуст я так понимаю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решился вопрос.

Это все новые фишки инстаграма. Дело в том, что с 17 ноября 2015 года все новые приложения работают в режиме песочницы.

Это означает, что вы можете получить по хештегу только картинки пользователя песочницы. В данном случае владельцем токена был я, а у меня фоток с хештегом 'kiev' банально не было.

Вот почему приходил пустой ответ. Добавил фото с нужным хэштегом и все заработало как нужно

Answer (score 1):

Ссылка вида "https://www.instagram.com/your_login/media/" - возвращает JSON-массив с фото и данными профиля.
Сейчас достаточно только такой записи. Нужно указать логин и всё:

```
$user = 'username';
$url = "https://www.instagram.com/$user/media/";
$ch = curl_init($url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
$json = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);

$result =  json_decode($json, true);

if (count($result['items'])) {
    foreach ($result['items'] as $_item) {
        echo '<img src="' . $_item['images']['thumbnail']['url'] . '">';
    }
}
```

Данная запись позволяет получать до 20 фоток с инсты! И главное без всяких там token-ов и uder_id!